# Spark Naive Bayes Result accuracy (Spark ML 1.6.0)

Tags: apache-spark, naivebayes

I am using Naive Bayes (Spark ML 1.6.0) for calculating the probability, but results i.e probability for class (I have only 2 class as can be seen in below example) is not coming proper, by proper I mean I calculated the probability manual using Bayes formula (data used in very simple and just 3 records as I want to do POC and first establish that result are correct).

CODE I used is here

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, Tokenizer}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, Row}


object NVTestDebug {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("PipelineSC")
    val sc: JavaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    // Prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
    val training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (0L, "10", 5.0),
      (1L, "10", 6.0),
      (2L, "10", 6.0)
    )).toDF("id", "text", "label")

    // Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of three stages: tokenizer, hashingTF, and lr.
    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
      .setInputCol("text")
      .setOutputCol("words")
    val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
      .setNumFeatures(1000)
      .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
      .setOutputCol("features")
    val nb = new NaiveBayes().setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("label")

    val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, nb))

    // Fit the pipeline to training documents.
    val model = pipeline.fit(training)

    // Prepare test documents, which are unlabeled (id, text) tuples.
    val test = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (17L, "10")
    )).toDF("id", "text")

    // Make predictions on test documents.
    model.transform(training).show(false)
    model.transform(test).show(false)
  }
}
```

I expect results to be 33.33 percentage probability for class 5.0 And 66.66 for class 6.0, Please let me know if expected result are wrong here

Actual Results are 30.7 and 69.2 as can be seen in below image

[DataFrames after transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdfNv.png)

I don't think the questio is duplicate with the mentioned one (mentioned by @zero323 ) beacsue of following
- In the mentioned link context is about unseen data, but for this question test data is not unknown
- Also probabailities are not coming too high or too low, instead they are coming with some deviation with what I calculated manually

Adding here different data set where results are not slightly different but difference is huge (please see the image), here as there is only 1 class for test data 10 for class 5.0 I expect probabailities to be near 100 and same for test data 20 for class 6.0 i.e near 100 percent for class 6.0 for test data 20
but results are ~ 88 % for test data 10 for class 5.0 and ~ 50% for test data 20 for class 6.0

[image: Data set 2 with results]

Comment: Yes right probability are slightly different, but I tried with some variation of data and difference is not small, I will post training data and result (same program with different training data)

Comment: edited post to add another data set I talked about

Comment: And it will be different. Formula which is used to compute these is not (and it not intended to be) equivalent to the conditional probability. I explained how these values are computed in the linked question.

Comment: ok, Just to clarify , you are referring to ""Laplace correction to avoid zeros" part in your answer right

Comment: No. I am actually to the part which describes how `rawPrediction` is computed (ignoring denominator) and how it is converted to probability `exp(raw - max(raw)) / sum(exp(raw - max(raw)))`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, one follow up question I have, when I set smoothing to 0 or near 0 all probabilities matching with expected one, why is it so, given that the formula used to compute is not identical to conditional probability